# Split on different newlines

Tags: ruby, regex, split, newline

Right now I'm doing a `split` on a string and assuming that the newline from the user is `\r\n` like so:

```
string.split(/\r\n/)
```

What I'd like to do is split on either `\r\n` or just `\n`.

So how what would the regex be to split on either of those?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Did you try `/\r?\n/` ?  The `?` makes the `\r` optional.

Example usage: http://rubular.com/r/1ZuihD0YfF

Comment: This is the right solution to the wrong problem. You shouldn't be geting `\r`s in your text.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, why do you assume the user should never have `\r`'s in his text?

Comment: what if the lines are only \r?

Answer (score 18):

Ruby has the methods `String#each_line` and `String#lines`

returns an enum:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-each_line

returns an array:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-lines

I didn't test it against your scenario but I bet it will work better than manually choosing the newline chars.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. For some reason, it's keeping the `\n\r`, I had to use `.map(&:squish)` on the array.

Comment: This solution is not applicable, as it does not consider different newline sequences: `String#lines` splits on the input record separator `$/` by default ([see](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-lines)), which is newline (`"\n"`) by default ([see](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/globals_rdoc.html)). However, no need to consider different newline chars as Ruby does it already ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6566121)).

Answer (score 15):

```
# Split on \r\n or just \n
string.split( /\r?\n/ )
```

Although it doesn't help with this question (where you do need a regex), note that `String#split` does not require a regex argument. Your original code could also have been `string.split( "\r\n" )`.

Answer (score 6):

```
\n is for unix 
\r is for mac 
\r\n is for windows format
```

To be safe for operating systems. I would do /\r?\n|\r\n?/

```
"1\r2\n3\r\n4\n\n5\r\r6\r\n\r\n7".split(/\r?\n|\r\n?/)
=> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "", "5", "", "6", "", "7"]
```

Comment: the most complete answer, don't understand why no up more upvotes. On mac file all other solution are not doing any split

Answer (score 3):

The alternation operator in Ruby `Regexp` is the same as in standard regular expressions: `|`

So, the obvious solution would be

```
/\r\n|\n/
```

which is the same as

```
/\r?\n/
```

i.e. an optional `\r` followed by a mandatory `\n`.

Comment: "The same as"?  Not necessarily.  Generally, it's good to avoid `|` in regular expressions when possible, as it makes them more inefficient.

Comment: @NickAldwin: I meant semantically. I'd think that any halfway decent compiler should be able to merge common prefixes and suffixes and turn the first form into the second one, no? After all, `Regexp` are not Turing-complete (well, Ruby 1.9's actually maybe *are*), so, unlike normal programming languages, not every optimization attempt automatically involves solving the Halting Problem.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Are you reading from a file, or from standard in?</s>

If you're reading from a file, and the file is in text mode, rather than binary mode, or you're reading from standard in, you won't have to deal with `\r\n` - it'll just look like `\n`.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\username>irb
irb(main):001:0> gets
foo
=> "foo\n"
```

Comment: For some more details about this, see [this blog post](https://www.rubytapas.com/2016/12/14/ruby-code-on-windows/#orgheadline14).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps do a split on only '\n' and remove the '\r' if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [String#chomp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp), which also handles newlines intelligently by itself.

You can accomplish what you are after with something like:

```
lines = string.lines.map(&:chomp)
```

Or if you are dealing with something large enough that memory use is a concern:

```
<string|io>.each_line do |line|
  line.chomp!
  #  do work..
end
```

Performance isn't always the most important thing when solving this kind of problem, but it is worth noting the chomp solution is also a bit faster than using a regex.

On my machine (i7, ruby 2.1.9):

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
           map/chomp    14.715k i/100ms
  split custom regex    12.383k i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
           map/chomp    158.590k (± 4.4%) i/s -    794.610k in   5.020908s
  split custom regex    128.722k (± 5.1%) i/s -    643.916k in   5.016150s
```