# Enter multiline string into textbox, and then split the result by newline

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, split

In my application a user can enter a string in a textbox that has multi lines such as the following:

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
```

This result is stored in a table as follows "This is line 1 This is line 2".

What I want is to be able to split the string by a newline after pulling it out of the table. Something like this:

```
 "This is line 1 This is line 2".split('/n')
```

To allow me to give the original result where the string spanned separate lines. However it doesn't seem to 'remember' the original string was over 2 lines. What is the best way to do this split?

Comment: `'\n'` doesn't mean what you want because the escape needs to be evaluated. You have to do `"\n"` but to consider the differences between OSs, Zakoff's answer will be better.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following for this to work:

```
"This is line 1 This is line 2".split(/\r?\n/)
```

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551128/split-on-different-newlines)